# Windows 7 Python 3.6.8 pip installed Spyder 3.3.2 throws a Kernel error - "zmq.error.zmqerror:bad address"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, spyder, pyzmq

1) I first installed python 3.6.8 from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/ I have set the appropriate path variables (path (to python & Python scripts directory) & PYTHONPATH (to DLLs and Lib directory)) and double checked the version on cmd. It seems to work there.

2) I then installed Spyder 3.3.2 from https://pypi.org/project/spyder/3.3.2/#files.  installed the wheel file then unzipped the archive file and `pip install spyder` from the directory

3) When I started Spyder using `python bootstrap.py`, spyder starts up with a kernel error. I get the same error when I tried installing from anaconda distribution as well.

Here is the ZMQ error I receive

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File
"C:\PortableApps\spyder.3.2\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line
1554, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle) File
"C:\Users\Abinayan.parthiban\Python\Python36\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py",
line 261, in start_kernel self._connect_control_socket() File
"C:\Users\Abinayan.parthiban\Python\Python36\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py",
line 210, in _connect_control_socket self._control_socket =
self.connect_control() File
"C:\Users\Abinayan.parthiban\Python\Python36\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
line 571, in connect_control return
self._create_connected_socket('control', identity=identity) File
"C:\Users\Abinayan.parthiban\Python\Python36\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
line 543, in _create_connected_socket sock =
self.context.socket(socket_type) File
"C:\Users\Abinayan.parthiban\Python\Python36\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py",
line 146, in socket s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type,
**kwargs) File "C:\Users\Abinayan.parthiban\Python\Python36\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py",
line 59, in __init__ super(Socket, self).__init__(*a, **kw) File
"zmq\backend\cython\socket.pyx", line 328, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.__init__ zmq.error.ZMQError: Bad
address
```

I can't for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated.